# How to programmatically check if Chrome app has permission to access the network?

Tags: android, android-permissions, trusted-web-activity

Some ROM's like Xiaomi's MIUI allows the user to disable network access for a given app:

[image: switch mobile network access for whatsapp]
[Font: pcmobitech](https://www.pcmobitech.com/block-internet-access-apps-xiaomi-mi-redmi-phones/)

I am working in a `TWA` application and in ROM's like the Xiaomi, is possible to block Chrome's network access.

**Is there a way to programmatically check if Chrome has access to the network?**

Things to consider:

- I've already try to use [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) with `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, `INTERNET` and `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` permissions.
- I do not want to add a permission for my app.
- Checking for network access does not work either because the smartphone has internet access, the ROM is blocking a specific app to access it.

Comment: Do you want to add permission for your app or all app ? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @XaviJimenez I do not want to add a permission. I want to check if a third-party (e.g. Chrome) has network access.